# Multiple blade effects in single swipe in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How can we implement multiple blade effects in single swipe in cocos2d?

I have implemented a blade effect by using **CCblade** class but it works for single blade effect. My requirement is, three blade effects with gaps between them in single swipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a "container" class for your blade effect, add 3 blade effects as its child nodes, set their position to make gaps between them. Spawn this container when swipe, that should do the trick.

Comment: its working great.... thanks a lot                                                                                 touchSprite.position = CGPointMake(touchMoved.x, touchMoved.y);
                    [bleadeffects addObject:touchSprite];
                    [blead push:touchMoved];                        
                    touchSprite1.position = CGPointMake(touchMoved.x - 20, touchMoved.y - 20);[bladeEffects1 addObject:touchSprite1];
 [blade1 push:ccp(touchMoved.x - 20, touchMoved.y - 20)];
    [bubbleEffcects2 addObject:touchSprite2];[blade2 push:ccp(touchMoved.x + 20, touchMoved.y +20)];